# Do I need a work visa for my time in Germany?

Tags: usa, germany, working-visas

I'm planning a summer trip to see my parents that live in Germany, and wondering if I'll be able to work a couple days WITHOUT needing a Visa. I'm trying to not have to use all my Paid time off. Here are the circumstances:

- we'll be visiting for 5 weeks
- I want to work 10 days total while there
- I will be working for an American company
- I will be working from an American Military base in Germany
- This is very much a personal trip first. We are going to visit family and give my kids some much needed grandparent time

Would I need a working visa to work those ten days from what is technically American soil?

Comment: Only persons subject to the NATO **Status of Forces Agreement** (SOFA) are exempt from the general residence/work permit regulations (mostly with an 'Official' (maroon) passport or a 'no fee' passport - special endorcement on page 26). If you enter in Germany as a visitor (with a tourist passport), the normal rules apply. **'is technically American soil' = nonsense**. Just as with an Embassy or Consulate special rules exist based on agreements.

Comment: As a US citizen you can make such an application after your arrival at the local immigration office. If a Military base exists nearby, they may be familiar with the situation.

Comment: US military bases in Germany are not "American soil," technically or otherwise.